# why is an Int not an Int inside an interface?

Tags: kotlin, integer

I have this function in side an interface

```
    interface test<Int>{
        fun printInt():Int {
            return 2}}
```

The error is: the integer literal doesn't conform to the expected type Int.

1. If I change the return type to `kotlin.Int`, the error goes away.

```
    interface test<Int>{
        fun printInt(): **kotlin.Int** {
            return 2}}
```

2. I don't use return, it works fine like this:

```
    interface test<Int>{
            fun printInt() = 2
    }
```

3. if I get the printInt function out of the interface, the compiler doesn't complain:

```
    fun printInt(): **Int** {
                return 2}
```

what are these Int#1 and kotlin.Int?

Comment: Why is your interface declared as `interface test<Int> { ...`? What makes you think you should write `<Int>` there? If you did `interface test { ...`, you would not get this error. Your answer to this could reveal where your actual misunderstanding about this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration:

```
interface test<Int>
```

declares a [generic interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), with a *type parameter* called `Int`. This is similar to how [`MutableList`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt#L179) is a generic interface with a type parameter called `E`:

```
public interface MutableList<E>
```

Therefore, inside the interface, the unqualified name "`Int`" refers to the type parameter, (similar to how inside `MutableList`, `E` refers to the type parameter) not the `kotlin.Int` type.